# Java - using multiple rates to calculate time

Tags: java

I have a homework problem that I could use a little help with.
I have an exploratory robot that I need to create a class for in which I can command it to move and return various different things about its status.

It has an initial rate at which it is moving of 5.0 units. I used this rate and the distance is has traveled to calculate the time it has been exploring.

I have to create a method that allows the user to change the rate multiple times and still calculate the time it has been traveling, with each part calculated at the rate it was traveling at the time.

Ex: The robot moves 50 fields at the rate of 5.0, then the rate is changed to 6.0 for 20 fields, then 2.0 for 80 fields. 
Something along those lines.

Here's what I have for the object class so far.

```
private int xcoord, ycoord; 
private int identification; 
private double rate; 
private double traveled; 

//Sets up a robot with the given ID number and beginning x and y coordinates
public Robot (int id, int x, int y) 
{
  identification = id;
  xcoord = x;
  ycoord = y;
  traveled = 0;
  rate = 5.0;
}

//Has the robot travel to the set coordinates
public double setDestination (int x, int y)
{
  double distance = Math.pow(x - xcoord, 2) + Math.pow(y - ycoord, 2);
  traveled += Math.sqrt(distance);
  xcoord = x;
  ycoord = y;
  return traveled;
}

//Gets the time spent travelling
public double getTimeSpent()
{
  return traveled/rate;
}

//Sets the rate at which the robot travels
public void setRate(double setrate)
{
  rate = setrate;
}

//Returns the ID of the robot
public int getID()
{
  return identification;
}
```

I figure I will need to change my getTimeSpent() method, but I'm not sure how to change it so that it takes each leg of the journey at its individual rate. As set up right now, it will return the time of the whole journey at the last rate that was set.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Update your time spent traveling while traveling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you do something along the lines of this? Pretty much create an instance variable `timeSpent` and update that in `setDestination` using the distance traveled that time only instead of the whole distance, with the current rate and return it in `getTimeSpent`

```
private int xcoord, ycoord; 
private int identification; 
private double rate; 
private double traveled; 
private double timeSpent;

//Sets up a robot with the given ID number and beginning x and y coordinates
public Robot (int id, int x, int y) 
{
  identification = id;
  xcoord = x;
  ycoord = y;
  traveled = 0;
  rate = 5.0;
}

//Has the robot travel to the set coordinates
public double setDestination (int x, int y)
{
  double distance = Math.pow(x - xcoord, 2) + Math.pow(y - ycoord, 2);
  traveled += Math.sqrt(distance);
  xcoord = x;
  ycoord = y;
  timeSpent += Math.sqrt(distance)/rate;
  return traveled;
}

//Gets the time spent travelling
public double getTimeSpent()
{
  return timeSpent;
}

//Sets the rate at which the robot travels
public void setRate(double setrate)
{
  rate = setrate;
}

//Returns the ID of the robot
public int getID()
{
  return identification;
}
```

Comment: Yup, that worked. Right as you posted I just thought of trying it in a different method and you  beat me to it. Thanks!

Comment: Sweet, glad you thought of it as well!

Answer (score 0):

Introduce another member to the class, say `travelLog`, which will be a list of pairs `TravelLogEntry: (rate, distanceTraveledAtRate)` -- that can be another class you'll have to create.

Something like this:

```
List<TravelLogEntry> travelLog = new ArrayList<TravelLogEntry>();
```

In `setRate()` you'll need to save the current rate and the distance traveled at the current rate to the `travelLog`, and then set the new rate:

```
travelLog.add(new TravelLogEntry(this.rate, this.traveled));
this.rate = newRate;
distance = 0;
```

In `getTimeSpent()` iterate over `travelLog` and compute time spent for each of its entries while accumulating the time in some temporary variable:

```
long totalTimeSpent = 0;
// go throught all the previous rates/distances
for(TravelLogEntry entry: travelLog){
    totalTimeSpent += entry.traveled/entry.rate;
}

// and don't forget the current rate:
totalTimeSpent += traveled/rate;
```

In the end `totalTimeSpent` will contain the total time the robot traveled, adjusted to different travel rates.

This should do the trick.

**UPDATE**: Nevermind, I guess, @austin's solution is way simpler.

Comment: Lol this would work, and it could be better than my solution if the OP had the need to see where they have been.

Comment: We haven't really worked with Arrays yet, although from what I do know about Java, this would be a much more useful solution. Austin's solution is simpler and worked for my needs right now though. Thanks for your answer!